# Is it normal to have a pair of slight bumps on the left edge of an iPad Mini screen?

Tags: ipad, display

I got an iPad mini a few days ago. Yesterday while using an app on it I noticed that, if I moved my finger up on the left edge of the display screen, I could feel a set of two slight bumps on the screen.

However if I look at the area it does not look uneven at all. And the device seems to work fine.

So I am not sure if this sort of slight bumpiness in a particular location is as expected.

**Question:**

Is it normal to have a pair of slight bumps on the left edge of an iPad Mini screen?

The bumps are in the display area marked in below photo (iPad Mini has [this SUPCASE case](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0157AK9Z8) on it so it looks a bit different). I have not put a screen protector on the device though.

**Side note:** the general area where the bumps are does have a persistent white dot which I suspect could be a dead pixel(?). Not sure if it is related.

[image: ipad screen]

Comment: Are you sure this is an iPad mini?  The object in the picture doesn’t look like one.

Comment: Looks like dust under the screen protector.

Comment: hi @bjbk, yes it is an iPad mini. It is just wearing one of those [SUPCASE covers](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0157AK9Z8) in the picture. But I did not put a screen protector on it though.

Comment: The link you added shows a screen protector is built into the case.  Are you sure there is not some membrane over the screen with dust trapped underneath?  Did you install the case yourself?

Comment: that is a good point @bjbk. What happened is that I had ordered that SUPCASE product but had my daughter put it on the iPad. I did not even notice that it came with some kind of a screen protector. I will have it checked out. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case linked to in the OP’s question has a built in screen protector.  There is dust or debris trapped between the screen and the protector membrane.

Removing the case and protector then cleaning the screen according to the installation instructions then reinstalling the case should fix the problem.

From the [SUPCASE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0157AK9Z8) product description:

> Front cover with Built-in screen protector prevents Scratches without compromising sensitivity